# PDO stop execution of transaction on duplicate PK

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am inserting data into a table like this:

```
$queryUpdatePosts = "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = $id";
error_log('user: '.$_SESSION['userid'].' post '.$id);
$userId = $_SESSION['userid'];
$queryInsertUserLike = "INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES ($userId, $id)";
try {
    $db -> beginTransaction();
    $statement1 = $db -> prepare($queryInsertUserLike);
    $statement1 -> execute();
    $statement2 = $db -> prepare($queryUpdatePosts);
    $statement2 -> execute();
    $row  = $statement -> fetch();
    $db -> commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db -> rollback();
}
```

in the "LIKES" table, user_id and post_id are defined as primary-key like this

```
ALTER TABLE likes
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`, `user_id`)
```

Now what I want my statement to behave is, quit execution when $statement1 fails because of PK.

I hope it's clear what I want and that anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to quote you on -

> " Now what I want my statement to behave is, quit execution when
>   $statement1 fails because of PK."

In that case, if :

```
if($statement1->rowCount() < 1){
   //quite execution 

}
```

BTW: You are doing mysql-like querying while using PDO. So, this line:

```
$queryInsertUserLike = "INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES ($userId, $id)";
```

Should be parameterized, like:

```
$queryInsertUserLike = "INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

then `execute` using..

`execute(array($_SESSION['userid'], $id)`)

Comment: I know about the values, that's to be changed, thanks! How do I actually "QUIT" the execution? throw Exception?

Comment: Nothing, if row count is 0, just skip the execution, and evaluate another code